# "If ... or if..." versus if ... or

Tags: conditional-constructions, ellipsis

If we consider the following sentences:

- > If we go right or if we climb to the roof, the alarm goes off.
- > If we go right or we climb to the roof, the alarm goes off.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid repetition you can leave out *we* and *if* after *and*,*but* and *or*.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct and convey equal meaning. You can dispense with the repeated “we” in the second sentence.